# Character encoding issues when requesting a given resource

Tags: encoding, http-headers

I'm building a crawler for users to post links and get a preview of the contents of the page, and I can't figure out why sometimes I get `�` when requesting a particular resource, even though Facebook seems to crawl it properly. I must be missing something.

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` to help me parse the HTML, and a default `WebClient` to help with making the actual requests. Here's the relevant code:

```
using (ExtendedWebClient client = new ExtendedWebClient())
{
    using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead(endpoint))
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            Encoding encoding = GetHttpResponseEncoding(client.ResponseHeaders);
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.Load(stream, encoding);
            return document.DeEntitize();
        }
    }
}

private Encoding GetHttpResponseEncoding(WebHeaderCollection headers)
{
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // use UTF-8 by default.
    string contentType = headers.Get("Content-Type");
    if (contentType != null) // expected form: "text/html; charset=utf-8".
    {
        string[] keyValuePairs = contentType.Split(';');
        foreach (string[] kvp in keyValuePairs.Select(kvp => kvp.Split('=')))
        {
            if (kvp.Length == 2 && kvp[0].Trim().ToLowerInvariant() == "charset")
            {
                // use the response header encoding.
                return Encoding.GetEncoding(kvp[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return encoding;
}

public static HtmlDocument DeEntitize(this HtmlDocument document)
{
    string html = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
    HtmlDocument decoded = new HtmlDocument();
    decoded.LoadHtml(html);
    return decoded;
}
```

The `ExtendedWebClient` just extends `System.Net.WebClient` by adding a `UserAgent` header impersonating a Firefox browser request.

The test code invokes the first piece of code with the following endpoint parameter:

```
new Uri("http://www.cronica.com.ar/diario/2012/07/30/30541-delpo-quiere-meterse-en-la-tercera-ronda.html")
```

Here's a small snippet from the page:

> Juan Mart�n Del Potro, que viene de vencer c�modamente al croata Ivan Dodig

**Even when opening that link in a browser window** (and looking at the source), I do get those enraging `�`.

The thing that is driving me nuts is that **Facebook is able to read this properly**. So what's the issue here, are they stating their encoding is `UTF-8` but not actually complying to that standard, or *what am I missing from the picture*?

Note that with this code I'm able to parse correctly pages like Facebook's spanish home, which does have characters like `ñ`, which could mean trouble when facing encoding issues, but this is *something else*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your parser is working fine. It's just that the page either **A)** is using mixed/incorrect encoding or **B)** is actually writing the unicode replacement character '�', ie the characters got munged somewhere before being output to the page (like going in/out the database). Where accents are correctly showing up, the page is using html entities, not the characters themselves.

if **A)** You could to try to detect coding (a pain, problematic).

if **B)** You can't do anything.

Comment: I'm reaching the conclusion they are using mixing encoding, if you load it up on firefox, `ISO-8859-1` works fine for some characters but not for others, and the same happens when using `UTF-8`, I guess I should use a `DecoderFallback` if I want to get around this issue?

Comment: That looks like your best bet. It's really just a method of failing gracefully. Just remember that garbage in = garbage out, you can only do so much with material that is outside of your control. You have to decide how worth your time it is to develop a framework around fixing someone else's mistakes and guessing their intentions.